# RealURL: Optional segments in FixedPostVars

Tags: typo3, lookup, realurl

I'm using RealURL in my Typo3 4.5.16 project for speaking URLs of a certain page. For this, I'm using a lookup-table that matches a certain number of IDs to their URL counterparts.

E.g.
`http://www.example.com/path/to/catalog/chapter1/section1/group1/prod-123/`
would map to page "catalog" with parameters mapped for `chapter`, `section`, `group`, and `product`, resp.
Note that only the **LAST** of those parameters is relevant and has a real mapping, the others are only there for a "pretty" path.

Now my problem: not every product has all levels of preceeding path segments. For example, another product might have a URL like this:
`http://www.example.com/path/to/catalog/chapter1/section4/prod-789/`

The database would look like this:

```
Id  | seg0      | seg1      | seg2      | seg3      | dummy0    | dummy1    | dummy2    | MapId
----|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
1   | chapter1  | section1  | group1    | prod-123  | 1         | 1         | 1         | 123
2   | chapter1  | section4  |           | prod-789  | 1         | 4         | 0         | 789
```

You see that the mapping to a segment name is just empty.

RealURL would however use an empty string as the group, and produce
`chapter1/section4//prod-789`

Is there a way to suppress such an empty mapping? Will decoding pass the segment to the next parameter (like `noMatch => bypass` for value maps)

If not, can multiple path segments be mapped at once using lookup table? (i.e. mapping the whole path to the real ID)?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try hooks that realUrl provides,  [see this article](http://www.t3node.com/blog/hiding-repeated-segments-with-realurl/)

Comment: Hooks apply to all URLs, but I only need it for 2 pages... But is worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a hacky workaround myself.

It uses `userFunc`tions, that basically mimic the behaviour of lookupTable. For every level there is one such function. It modifies the `$params['pathParts']` array that is passed to the unser functions

**Encoding:**

- For the "parent" levels, just map to the segment. This will return empty strings if not mapped.
- For the mapped level, remove all empty elements at the end of the passed `$params['pathParts']` array
- => Removes empty parts

**Decoding:**

- For the "parent" levels, check if there are more elements in `$params['pathParts']`. If not, this is a "skipped" parent. Just append the current value to the `$params['pathParts']`, which will be passed to the next level by RealURL
- The mapped level eventually is called with the correct value. Just map

It works as long as the handling of userFunctions is not changed too much by RealURL...